# Infragistics no licence information found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, infragistics

I try to load my project after I formatted my pc from win7 32bit to win8 64bit(might has something to do with the error) and the Infragistics licenses don't work. I have 8 Infragistics entries in my license.licx file and i get 8 errors in visual studio 2008. The error I get is this:

```
Error   1   Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid, Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v7.1, Version=7.1.20071.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: No license information found    C:\Users\Antonis\Desktop\Dropbox\BackUp\PETROLINA\CANTINE\23.04.2013 VISITORS working\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Petrolina receive order\Petrolina receive order\My Project\licenses.licx
```

And I installed the same version of Infragistics I had before. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you compile for AnyCPU Platform or x86?

Comment: My comment is related to the different way in which an x86 app reads the registry. I am not sure, but if your (rather old) version of Infragistics stores its license info in the registry there is the possibility that an app built with AnyCPU running on x64 system is unable to read the values stored in the 32bit part of the registry by a setup written for 32bit OS. Try switching the platforms and check if there is any difference

Comment: Srr now i read your 1st comment more carefully:P Em.. i compiled with all 3 options. anycpu x64 x86. the x64 gives my error about incorrect format and the program does not load at all. The other 2 i simply ignore the errors of the infragistics but obviously the ultragrids are not visible.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anymore that version. I think that is related to the above situation, but this could be resolved only by Infragistics team. They read this site, so, be hopeful.

Comment: I have just found this page on their site: http://www.infragistics.com/help/supported-environments/ It seems that you are out of luck. However I would ask them

Comment: @AntonisLambrianides I have been answering this question on the Infragistics Forums here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/80446.aspx

Comment: Did you try to contact Ingfragistics support about that?

Answer (score 1):

I`m not sure what is your Infragistics product and what is the version, but there are few limitations. For example for Windows Forms controls:
- NetAdvantage for .NET 2008 Volume 1 up to NetAdvantage for .NET 2012 Volume 1. could be use  with VS2008
- NetAdvantage 2012 Volume 1 and later. could be use with Win 8

and so on. My suggestion is to check supported-environments page for more details:
http://www.infragistics.com/help/supported-environments/ or ask Infragistics for assistance

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem going from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and found that many of the registry entries were missing for a very old version of Infragistics. To resolve, I exported this key and all sub-keys/values from the Windows Registry on the working computer: 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Infragistics\NetAdvantage\Net\Full\CLR2x\Version7.1]

I then removed the key/values already present and merged the registry file onto the new computer. This resolved the issue for me.